# asp.net internationalization with a single resource file for each language (for all pages)

Tags: asp.net, internationalization

is it possible to do internationalization in asp.net with just one resource file for all pages
(I know that by default you have to have resource files for each page)

Comment: one resource file for each language, but for all pages

Comment: Removed my initial comment, my misunderstanding, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have global and page level resources. If the file is in app_globalresources, it's meant to be a global resource file. If it's in app_localresources, it's meant to be a page level resource file.

Comment: and if i need to translate something that is not in the UI but in a separate class library like DomainModel, am i going to be able to do this ?

Comment: If it were in a separate class library, I'd bake the resources into the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see similar question: [Global resource vs. Local resource in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446321/global-resource-vs-local-resource-in-asp-net)

Resource link:

[ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)